Error: config.json Not Found When Deploying LLM on Mobile (Using Smol and Qwen)
I'm trying to deploy a small LLM on a mobile device and am experimenting with both Smol and Qwen models. However, I keep encountering an issue where it says that the config.json file isn't there.
        python {
            version "3.8"
            pip {
                options "--only-binary=:all:"
                install "transformers==4.15.0"
                install "tokenizers==0.10.3"
                install "torch==1.8.1"
                install "numpy==1.19.5"
                options "--no-binary=pyyaml"
                install "pyyaml==6.0.2"
            }
        }

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.chaquo.python'
}

from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM

# Use Chaquopy's asset directory
# checkpoint = "app:model_files/Qwen2-0.5B-Instruct"
checkpoint = "model_files/SmolLM-135M"
tokenizer = None
model = None

def initialize_model():
    global tokenizer, model
    try:
        tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint, local_files_only=True)
        model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(checkpoint, local_files_only=True)
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(f"Error loading model: {str(e)}. Model path: {checkpoint}")

def interpret_text(text):
    try:
        if tokenizer is None or model is None:
            initialize_model()
        inputs = tokenizer.encode(text, return_tensors="pt")
        outputs = model.generate(inputs, max_length=50)
        return tokenizer.decode(outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
    except Exception as e:
        return f"Error in Python code: {str(e)}"

I have double-checked and confirmed that the file is indeed in the correct folder.
I suspect this might be related to the libraries I'm using, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Has anyone else encountered a similar issue, or does anyone have suggestions on how to resolve this?
Thanks in advance for your help!
